# Separacion entre los puntos de los ejes

Tags: c#, wpf

tengo una aplicación para mostrar puntos de una tabla de valores (x,y) en una `polilinea`, para ello uso un `canvas` y un `pointcollection`

Mi duda es si puedo hacer que la separación entre los puntos sea mayor

Me explico con una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Polyline polilinea2 = new Polyline();
        PointCollection puntos2 = new PointCollection();
        xrealmin = -200; xrealmax = 200; yrealmin = -200; yrealmax = 200;
        xpantmin = 0; xpantmax = grafica.ActualWidth; ypantmin = 0; ypantmax = grafica.ActualHeight;
        polilinea2.Stroke = Brushes.Red;

        if (e.aux == 1)
        {
            grafica.Children.Clear();
            ejes();
        }


        dibujar(polilinea2, puntos2, e.hojas, e.selected);
        grafica.Children.Add(polilinea2);

 public Point escalar(int x, int y)
    {
        xreal = x;
        yreal = y;
        xpant = ((xpantmax - xpantmin) * (xreal - xrealmin) / (xrealmax - xrealmin) + xpantmin)+10;
        ypant = (ypantmin - ypantmax) * (yreal - yrealmin) / (yrealmax - yrealmin) + ypantmax;
        Point p = new Point(xpant, ypant);
        return p;
    }

    public void dibujar(Polyline p, PointCollection pc, List<Hojas> h, int selected)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(selected.ToString());
        if (selected!=-1 && h.Count>0 && h[selected].lp.Count>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < h[selected].lp.Count; i++)
            {
                pc.Add(escalar(h[selected].lp[i].x, h[selected].lp[i].y));
            }

            p.Points = pc;
            nHoja.Content = h[selected].name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Explicate mostrando el codigo que implementaste hasta ahora, ademas del dibujo.

Comment: actualizado con algo de codigo, lo que quiero hacer simplemente es aumentar el espacio entre un punto y otro para que se vea mejor, por ejemplo los puntos (100, 100) y (101,100) no se aprecian debido a la cercania @gbianchi